# Assigning unique ROW NUMBER() for all the PARTITIONED RECORDS

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

In this query it is partitioning the records but i need to assign row number for all the result set a row number should not be repeated it should be unique fpr each row.Anyone help ? Thanks in advance.

```
select *
from Store  
order by 
   row_number() over (partition by category order by storename),category
```

Table cloumn sample in SQLFIDDLE :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/767ab/86

I want output in the format of :

```
RowNo     Category  
1         Fruits
2         Chocs
3         Vegetables
4         Fruits
5         Chocs
6         Vegetables
..........
```

Comment: If you need one for every row remove `partition by`: `row_number() over (order by storename)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But in my table im having category column. For eg say im having category : Fruits (10 records), category : Chocolates (10 records) category : vegetables(10 records). in my result i want 1. one record from fruits, one record from chocolate, one records from vegetables again this sequence should continue like one record from chocolate, one records from vegetables.. fruits, chocltae, vegtable..... after partitioning i want unique row number for each record

Comment: Please update the question with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Category) rn, *
    FROM    STORE
)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn, Category) rn ,
        StoreId ,
        StoreName ,
        Category ,
        Price ,
        Quantity ,
        Address 
FROM    data
ORDER BY 1
```

This is producing the following sequence:

```
1   CHOCOS
2   FRUITS
3   ICECREAM
4   VEGETABLES
5   CHOCOS
6   FRUITS
7   ICECREAM
8   VEGETABLES
9   CHOCOS
10  FRUITS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to give unique row number then don't use partition by only order by 
Please Try following query .

```
select *,row_number() over (order by storename) As RowNumber
from Store  
order by 
   row_number() over (order by storename),Category
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But in my table im having category column. For eg say im having category : Fruits  (10 records), category : Chocolates (10 records) category : vegetables(10 records). in my result i want 1. one record from  fruits, one record from chocolate, one records from vegetables again this sequence should continue like one record from chocolate, one records from vegetables.. fruits, chocltae, vegtable.....  after partitioning i want unique row number  for each record

Comment: Hello , I am not sure. but you can try following query

select  *, row_number() over ( order by storename)
from Store  
order by 
   row_number() over (partition by category order by storename),category

Answer (score 0):

Don't use partition by clause

```
select *
from Store  
order by 
   row_number() over (order by storename),category
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/767ab/93)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But in my table im having category column. For eg say im having category : Fruits (10 records), category : Chocolates (10 records) category : vegetables(10 records). in my result i want 1. one record from fruits, one record from chocolate, one records from vegetables again this sequence should continue like one record from chocolate, one records from vegetables.. fruits, chocltae, vegtable..... after partitioning i want unique row number for each record

Comment: Can You please Show EXPECTED output.. @shalini

Comment: Rowno :1    category : fruits,Rowno :2    chocs: fruits,Rowno :3   category : vegtables,Rowno :4  category : fruits,Rowno :5   category : chocs,Rowno :6   category : vegetables...........

Answer (score 0):

```
     select * into #temp
     from(
        select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Category ORDER BY Category) AS Row_Number
        from Store) x  



     select ROW_NUMBER,StoreName,Category,Price,Quantity,
     ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ROW_NUMBER,category)  as uniquerownum from #temp
     group by Row_Number,StoreName,Category,Price,Quantity
```

sample:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/767ab/138

take it easy ....

Comment: rownumber Category storename

Comment: 2. Chocolate, KR store

Comment: No sir its not working. I need unique row number for ea record.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Category) AS Id, -- New Id
    * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY StoreName) PartitionId, * 
        FROM Store
    ) data
WHERE 
    PartitionId = 1 -- Get one record for each category
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/767ab/122)

Comment: i want all the records repeating with the sequence order and each row should have unique number

Answer (score -1):

```
select x.*,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by rownum,category)  as uniquerownum
from
      (select *,row_number() over (partition by category order by category) rownum
       from Store) x
order by rownum,category
```

Comment: ahh sir thank yu so much. This is working for me thank yu so much. but here im using joins also both the table in join having same column name so it is showing MULTI-Part Identifier

Comment: I am a girl.. :D
Also please tick mark it right if u find the answer is correct ...

Comment: mam your query is working for me . but i need to use that uniquerowno in where clause is it possible ??

Comment: mam im waiting for yur reply.. im also trying to use that uniquerowno in where clause it not wrking.

Comment: SELECT Y.*
FROM(
    SELECT x.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY rownum, category) AS uniquerownum
    FROM(
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY category) rownum
        FROM #Store) x) Y
WHERE Y.uniquerownum=1
ORDER BY rownum, category;

Comment: This is working for me thank yu so much. but here im using joins also both the table in join having same column name so it is showing MULTI-Part Identifier

Comment: Thank yu so much mam its  workingThank yu thanks a lot.i will try mam.